# Crop a picture with CSS

Tags: html, image, css

I am doing a Userstyle for a Website, so I can only change the CSS.

They generate their pictures with a white border at the top and the bottom which I want to get rid off.

The HTML-structure looks like this:

```
<a>
 <img></img>
 <span></span>
</a>
```

The span is a little coloured text-field, which overlaps the img, so putting overflow: hidden on the a doesnt work. (Because it will crop the span too)

I also tried using a border, but that didn't get me anywhere.

Is there another way?

EDIT: Here is a [codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/YXdWrw) of my problem

Comment: can you make the images appear as a css background rather than as an img tag? you'd have a lot more flexibility to change how the image shows up that way.

Comment: You can use [clip-path](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/clip-path), no IE support though, but since you're making a userstyle you probably don't need it.

Comment: Tanks for your help, unfortunately only the method with an inline svg ([as shown here](http://codepen.io/imohkay/pen/GJpxXY))seems to work for my browser and I don't see how I would accomplish that with a userstyle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

trautmann, take a look here: 
https://jsfiddle.net/0qc27otz/

```
.wrapper {
    background-color: grey;
  padding-bottom: 4em;
  padding-left: 4em;
  padding-top: 4em;
    width: 100%;
    float: left;
}


     div.wrapper a{
        border: none;
        display: block;
        position: relative;
        float: left;
        width: auto;
        height: 165px;
        overflow: hidden;
      }

      div.wrapper a img{
        display: block;
        position: relative;
        width: 100%;
        margin-top: -5px;

      }
    .myspan {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 20px;
      left: 5%;
      width: 10%;
    color: #FFF;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-weight: bold;
    height: 16px;
    background: red;
    }
```

is that what you need?

Comment: a bit edited the "Tech" button: https://jsfiddle.net/0qc27otz/1/

Comment: Hi Eugene, thanks for you post, the problem with you solution is, that the "Tech" label will not fully display if its overlapping the images border. It should stand out a little bit. EDIT: Look at the codepen I posted.

Comment: if it should go out from images border, place it out of "<a>" and edit css accordingly. The jsfiddle I was working with is not showing me things now for some reason. Will you hand some other example, I can show you how I would do what you ask.

Comment: I have the same problem with jsfiddle, do you mind trying it with codepen?

Comment: please give me the link, I will

Comment: I think I found your original link and edited: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/yNGVJa

Comment: Hey, in your version the span is outside of the <a>, but I can't do that, here is the codepen link, which is also in my original post under "EDIT:" http://codepen.io/anon/pen/YXdWrw

Comment: take a look at this: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/aOPBRj

Comment: Oh nice, thanks, did not know that clip property. I think I can get this to work. Thank you
PS: if you post "use the clip property" and the codepen link as an answer, I will upvote and mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 1):

As quantumwannabe said in the comments, you can use clip-path like so:

```css
img {
  -webkit-clip-path: inset(10px);
  clip-path: inset(10px);
}
```

```html
<img src="http://placehold.it/300x125">
```

Browser support is [quite bad](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-clip-path) to be honest. Here's a [fun tool](http://bennettfeely.com/clippy/) to play with the property.

Comment: Thanks, but this method doesn't work with firefox.

Answer (score 1):

You can use clip-path on top and bottom, add this to your CSS, if the browser don't support clip-path it will not the end of the world, it will show the border image.

```
a > img{
  /* top, right, bottom, left */
  -webkit-clip-path: inset(2px 0px 2px 0px);
  clip-path: inset(2px 0px 2px 0px);
}
```

#### Further Reading

- [Clipping in CSS and SVG — The clip-path Property and `<clipPath>` Element](http://sarasoueidan.com/blog/css-svg-clipping/)
- [Using clip-path](http://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/c/clip/)

Comment: Thanks, but this method doesn't work with firefox.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to take a look here:
http://cssdeck.com/labs/full/1z7osafa

I added classes to img, a and wrapped everything to div.

So the main idea is to make  to be blocks of definite height and hide the oversflow and also you can set any borders around.

Hope the code will be shown to you and you will understand it.
if no, here is html:

```
    <div class='SomeWrapper'>
    <a class='TheLinker' href='http://sdelanounas.ru/'>
      <img class='TheIMG' src='http://sdelanounas.ru/i/c/2/r/f_c2RlbGFub3VuYXMucnUvdXBsb2Fkcy82LzkvNjk1MTM4NjU3MDk5NF9vcmlnLmpwZWc_X19pZD00NDYwMg==.jpeg'/>
      <span class='sometext'>This Is a Great Plane</span>
    </a>
    <a class='TheLinker' href='topwar.ru/'>
      <img class='TheIMG' src='http://cdn.topwar.ru/uploads/posts/2014-03/1395891634_2249x1444_su-34-frontovoj-zaschitnik-fullback.jpg'/>
  <span class='sometext'>This Is a Great Plane</span>
    </a>    
    </div>
```

Here is CSS:

```
div.SomeWrapper{
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  float: left;
}
div.SomeWrapper{
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  float: left;
}
a.TheLinker{
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  width: 48%;
  margin: 0 1%;
  height: 18em;
  overflow: hidden;

}
a.TheLinker img{
  width: 100%;  
  border: none;
}

span.sometext{
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 1em;
  background: rgba(255,255,255, 0.8);
  color: #555;
  text-shadow: #ccc;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;

}
a.TheLinker img{
  width: 100%;  
  border: none;
}

span.sometext{
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 1em;
  background: rgba(255,255,255, 0.8);
  color: #555;
  text-shadow: #ccc;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;

}
```

I'm a newbie here so my code could be not properly formed, so sorry if something's not looking good..
If you have questions - ask, I think I really can help!

Comment: The OP has stated that the HTML cannot be changed.

Comment: nothing changes: CSS can be set for this particular case: a is anyway under some id so one can address it like this: #someId a and address to any tag through closest Id. Do you agree?

Comment: take a look here: https://jsfiddle.net/0qc27otz/1/